# Getting chef-client 11.14.6 for later MacOSX versions

Tags: macos, chef-infra

I have inherited a cheffed OSX machine running chef-client 11.14.6. I am trying to lay my hands on the installer for 11.14.6, but it seems that Chef have pulled it from the downloads site ( https://downloads.chef.io/chef-client/mac/ ).

Does anyone know anything about this, or know where I can get "archived" version?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any copies in any repos so it's probably lost to the mists of time by now. You should be able to build a new one using this commit from omnibus-chef https://github.com/chef/omnibus-chef/tree/6d5001c588edacc98f6045e22c70195200111660

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From my research, and the research of others. It seems as if it has been removed.

However, we (I can't take the credit - it was one of my colleagues :) ) managed to get it working. We had another machine with the correct version on it, so we grabbed it from there and zipped it up (using root as the base, and grabbing /opt/chef).

Once tarball (e.g. opt.chef-11.14.6.tar.gz) is transferred to new machine, these were the steps used:

1. install chef-client v11.10.4 using:

   (echo "version=11.10.4"; curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh) | sudo bash
2. verify your chef-client version is currently reported as 11.10.4 with "chef-client -v"
3. extract the tarball as root into the root filesystem using:

   cd / && tar xvfz /tmp/opt.chef-11.14.6.tar.gz
4. verify your chef-client version is now reported as 11.16.4 with "chef-client -v"
5. run your knife bootstrap command like normal, but don't include the --bootstrap-version parameter, it'll detect chef-client is already installed and use the one you have installed manually.

I did not try rebuilding it.

Comment: This is no longer applicable since El Captain https://github.com/chef/omnitruck/issues/189#issuecomment-231044808